# How to include the deleted elements when querying a "paranoid" table on sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I want that previously existing users on my application, that have been deleted using the paranoid mode (so now its field `deletedAt` is NOT `null`), to be able to register again using the same email. So when the API notices a user creation with a previously used email it sets to `null` the `deletedAt` field of the previously existing register instead of creating a new user.

Usually for looking for an user I will do,

`User.find( { where: { email: req.body.user.email } })`

But upon inspection of the SQL query created, it includes

`Users.deletedAt IS NULL`

Is there any special way of finding when dealing with paranoid models?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Just run your query like this:

```
User.find({
  where: {email: req.body.user.email}, 
  paranoid: false
})
```

Answer (score 15):

Sequelize has this feature built in. Per their API docs, you can include the 'paranoid' flag in the options of your find call.

e.g.

```
User.find({where: {email: req.body.user.email}}, {paranoid: false}).success(models) {
    //models contains both deleted and non-deleted users
}
```

Reference: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance

Comment: It also can query the data that is not be destroyed. sequelize version is 5.8.5

Answer (score 2):

You can use hook.

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid')
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define("multi_route", {
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: false,
        }
        //other fields
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid: true,
        hooks: {
            beforeUpdate: function (multiFare, next) {                  // berforeUpdate will called after beforeDestroy
                if (multiFare.email.indexOf("_____destroyed") > -1) {   // check contains '_____destroyed' string
                    multiFare.email = multiFare.email + uuid.v1()       // set unique value
                }
                next()
            },
            beforeDestroy: [function (multiFare, next) {                // beforeDestroy will called before one instance destroyed
                multiFare.email = multiFare.email + '_____destroyed'    // flag this will destroy
                next()
            }]
        }
    })
}
```

Sorry for my bad comments :(