# sequelize findone adding extra condition in query

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have node js with sequelize and mysql . I have used following syntax to find one record

```
 await SkillPlanUser.findOne({
        where: { deleted_at: {
          [Op.ne]: null
        },skill_plan_id: skill_plan_id, user_id: val },
      })
```

But its executing like below:

```sql
SELECT `id`,
       `skill_plan_id`,
       `user_id`,
       `created_at`,
       `updated_at`,
       `deleted_at`
FROM `skill_plan_user` AS `skill_plan_user`
WHERE (`skill_plan_user`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
       AND (`skill_plan_user`.`deleted_at` IS NOT NULL
            AND `skill_plan_user`.`skill_plan_id` = '3'
            AND `skill_plan_user`.`user_id` = '5'))
LIMIT 1;
```

In above query `skill_plan_user`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND` ...gets added even its not mentioned.

I am not getting why its get added and how I can remove that?

Please guide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include the deleted elements when querying a "paranoid" table on sequelize.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611778/how-to-include-the-deleted-elements-when-querying-a-paranoid-table-on-sequeliz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you indicated `paranoid: true` in the model options (that means you use soft-delete feature).
When the paranoid mode is turned on for the model then by default you will get all non-deleted records so there is no need to indicate this condition:

```js
deleted_at: {
          [Op.ne]: null
        }
```

Sequelize will do it itself (as you already found out).
If you want to get all records including deleted ones you need to indicate `paranoid: false` in `findOne` as Emma already mentioned in the comment.

```js
await SkillPlanUser.findOne({
        where: { skill_plan_id: skill_plan_id, user_id: val },
      }, { paranoid: false })
```